# fstab mount no longer working

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have an ubuntu share that I use infrequently. The last time I used it was about 11 months ago. At the time it worked.  I tried searching a solution but I could not find a solution.

I have the following entry in my /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.16.253/Movies_XMAS    /media/pms-movies_xmas  cifs    credentials=/etc/win-credentials2,,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

The path /media/pms-movies_xmas exists on the Ubuntu machine.

The share //192.168.16.253/Movies_XMAS exists (I can log in from another Windows machine).

The credential files exists and the chmod is 600.  If I `sudo cat /etc/win-credentials2` the credentials are correct.

Running sudo dmesg returns the following:

```
[ 3584.666443] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.16.253\Movies_XMAS
[ 3584.676534] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 3584.676555] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.16.253 Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 3584.676584] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I tried other parameters suggested in various forums but these did not resolve the issue.

My version of Ubuntu is 22.04.3 LTS.

Thanks

Comment: Error 13 is "Permission denied".  Also, the `/media/` tree is used by the automounter. Users shouldn't use it. Do `sudo mkdir /mnt`, and use that directory tree (`/mnt/disk1`, `/mnt/disk2` for your mount point.  Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: @waltinator. Thank you for share. I wasn't aware of the reservation. I corrected from my end

Answer (score 1):

The problem was from my end. The credentials were not correct. Once corrected everything worked